# How to achieve this layout on all devices excluding tablets

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am not worried about tablets at the moment, just android phones. I have some pay as you go LG phone that I use to develop on. I have a frame layout with a `VideoView` and a `WebView` in it.

My XML file defined the width and height at specific pixels and that worked fine for testing on my one device. I tried it on another device which had a larger screen and they dont fill the window like on my go phone.

I was wondering how I can fill the top half of the screen with my video and the bottom half with and image. I tried `layout_width` as `match_parent`, but then I wasn't sure how to define the height. Here is the layout I want to achieve on all devices.

[image: ss]

and my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mobile_vforum_bg"
    >
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/vidPlayer"
        android:layout_width="320px"
        android:layout_height="240px">
    </VideoView>
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/slideHolder"
        android:layout_width="320px" 
        android:layout_height="240px"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
     </WebView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Obviously I cant use a pixel amount here, so what are my options? Thank you and I hope my question was clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use a vertical linearlayout, and specify `layout_weight="1"` for both views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mobile_vforum_bg">
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/vidPlayer"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/slideHolder"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a `FrameLayout`?  That is meant for when you want to overlay views. In this case a simple `LinearLayout`with orientation="vertical" should do the trick.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mobile_vforum_bg"
    >
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/vidPlayer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/slideHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure I need to use FrameLayout. I removed a ListView that sits on top of both VideoView and WebView. It is opened via the Menu button. I removed it because I didn't think it was relevant to the question, but apparently I was mistaken. So with that said, I guess I am overlaying views.

Comment: I think I found the answer. I kept my layout the same, but rather than `320px` I did `320dip` and that seems to solve the issue across all the different resolutions

Comment: That is not going work across all phones.  If you need the FrameLayout for something else, than just put these two items within a LinearLayout within the FrameLayout.